# Adding elevation to shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation, 3d, srtm

I have a shapefile that's actually a polyline (but it's 200 miles!)
on the other hand I have a SRTM layer with elevation data.
[image]

How should I add the elevation data from SRTM layer to the shapefile?

I cannot use 3D "interpolate line" and draw a line because it's 200 miles!

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.

Comment: Is the shapefile z-enabled already?  (Ie, if you look at the shapefile properties, does it have a "Z Coordinate System" tab?)

Comment: Actually I have converted it to a 3D shapefile using "Feature to 3D By Attribute". now I have two shapefiles, the first is 2D and the second is 3D. is it OK?

Comment: Do you have 3d analyst? The tool Interpolate Shape https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Interpolate_Shape/00q90000006m000000/ will assert the Z values at each vertex from your raster. The tool you have used asserts the same value for the whole line making the line/polygon completely flat.

Comment: Not quite sure why the length of your linestring is prohibitive; it's more an issue of vertex density, but even at 3 meter intervals, 100k vertices shouldn't be disruptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @michael-stimson
I have found a solution based on your solution.

Steps:

you should convert your 2D Shapefile to a 3D shapefile by using "Interpolate Shape" tool:

Arc Toolbox -> 3D Analyst Tool -> Functional Surface -> **Interpolate Shape**.
[image]

now you should select your Input Surface, then select your 2D shapefile and then select your output shapefile (for example test_3D.shp)

after interpolation you have a 3D shapefile and add it to your Layers.
now select your 3D shapefile by using "Select Feature":

[image]

now your 3D line is selected as following:

[image]

now from 3D Analyst Toolbar, click on the "Profile Graph" as following:

[image]

now you see the result:

[image]

Thanks for your attentions.